# Unable to activate Xamarin Unhanded ERROR - Visual Studio 2015 update 2

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, azure-devops

I try to activate xamarin account on Visual Studo 2015 Update 2 the error is:

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>d__100.MoveNext()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass11.<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>b__12(Task t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this discussion in the Xamarin forums. There are listed several common issues. Your question's there as well:

[Xamarin for All! Stable Release: Xamarin 4, Cycle 6 – Service Release 3](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63596/xamarin-for-all-stable-release-xamarin-4-cycle-6-service-release-3)

Quoted from there:

> Ensure that you have updated all of your installed Xamarin packages on both Windows and Mac to match the versions listed under "Release Info" below.

Answer (score 0):

If you still having issues, goto Tool Menu , then Options, Under Xamarin, choose Other and then click on Check Update button, You should find an update pending ( 4.0.3.214), download that and try again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Xamarin to the latest stable version worked for me.