# Not Able to register my Xamarin account in VS2015

Tags: xamarin

I am getting below error when I am logging in `Xamarin` account in mY `VS2015`

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>d__100.MoveNext()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass11.<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>b__12(Task t)
```

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to activate Xamarin Unhanded ERROR - Visual Studio 2015 update 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385508/unable-to-activate-xamarin-unhanded-error-visual-studio-2015-update-2)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/188323/#Comment_188323) you need to:

- Update to the latest Stable ["Cycle 6 – Service Release 3"](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-3/) versions
- Log out and log back into your Xamarin account following the "Quick manual refresh steps" on https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1641743-how-do-i-manually-resynchronize-xamarin-licenses-.